# Calling object function through jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hi guys I would like to expose a problem...I have this situation for my web app:

//ROUTE

```
getRoute()->post('/aggiungiMateria', array("GestioneController","aggiungiMateria"));
```

//CONTROLLER

```
function aggiungiMateria(){
    try{
        $model     = new GestioneModel();
        $alunno = $model->aggiungiMateria();
        echo 'ok';
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo json_encode(array($e->getMessage()));
    }
}
```

//MODEL

```
function aggiungiMateria(){
    $nome = addslashes($_POST['nome']);
    try{    
        $db    = $this->getConnection();
        $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO materie SET nome = '$nome' ");
        $query->execute();
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

//HTML

```
<label>Materia</label>
<input type="text" id="nome" value="<?php echo $materia;?>" />                 
<input type="hidden" id="controllo" value="<?php echo $id?>"/>
<button onclick="gestione();">SALVA</button>
```

//JS AJAX

```
function gestione(){
    $('.loading').show();
    var nome = $('#nome').val();
    var id = $('#controllo').val();

    if(id!=''){

        $.post( "../../ws/modificaMateria", {       //NOT FOUND

            nome:nome,
            id:id
            }, 
            function( data ) {

                if(data=='ok'){
                    location.href='materie.php';
                }

            }, "html");
    }else{
        $.post( "../../ws/aggiungiMateria", {       //NOT FOUND

            nome:nome,
            id:id
            }, 
            function( data ) {

                if(data=='ok'){
                    location.href='materie.php';
                }

        }, "html");
    }
}
```

When click on SALVA button the debugger throw exception for /ws/aggiungiMateria not found with error 404 and f.send from jQuery-2.1.4.min give me uncaught error from chrome dev tools. I apologize for any errors in this post.

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: when I run javascript it gives me error ../../ws/aggiungiMateria not found 404 refer to jQuery-2.1.4.min.js... how can I refer to the internal function of GestioneModels.php?

Comment: You do know what a 404 error is, right?

Answer (score 0):

I solved by modifying the apache config file with the AllowOverride All directive